# PostgreSQL aggregate json objects into single json array

Tags: postgresql

I have data like:

| Name | PhoneNumber |
| --- | --- |
| Bob | `{"type":"mobile", "number":"1-234-567-8910"}` |
| Bob | `{"type":"work", "number":"1-555-555-5555"}` |
| Jane | `{"type":"mobile", "number":"1-333-333-3333"}` |

I would like to combine over "Name" to be in a single json array like so:

| PhoneNumbers |
| --- |
| `{"name": "Bob", "PhoneNumbers": [{"type":"mobile", "number":"1-234-567-8910"},{"type":"work", "number":"1-555-555-5555"}]}` |
| `{"name": "Jane", "PhoneNumbers": [{"type":"mobile", "number":"1-333-333-3333"}]}` |

I was looking at json_agg, but I am not sure how to group properly to get the results above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [JSON functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html):

```
SELECT jsonb_build_object(
          'name',
          name,
          'PhoneNumbers',
          jsonb_agg(phonenumber)
       )
FROM tab
GROUP BY name;
```

Comment: Thanks! This did the trick. I achieved it with (SELECT row_to_json(_) FROM (SELECT name, json_agg(PhoneNumbers) AS PhoneNumbers) AS _) AS t1, but yours is certainly more elegant